# mysql, need to update column with random dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 'timestamp' type column in my table called updated_date. When adding a column to the table, all rows got updated to the same updated_date. Not a disaster as we're still in testing, but it kind of broke the functionality of our site (which shows things in order of updated_date).

Is there a way I can change all the updated_date values in the column (but where id is lower than x) to some random date (or an incremental date)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let he who hasn't run an `update` without a `where` cast the first stone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might solve your problem:

```
UPDATE updated_table SET timestamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(1e9 + id) WHERE id < x;
```

Basically it sets dates to Unix timestamps corresponding to 1 billion + id (1,000,000,000 unix timestamp is 2001-09-08 21:46:40).  That way you get unique timestamps in order of id.

Comment: if he wants to make the date from any other date, he might as well calculate the starting time as he wishes but it will look kind of funny because I don't think 100,000 posts would've been posted in less than one day

Comment: I agree, you could use id*60 to set them one minute apart or something if that was important, or replace 1e9 with any other date.  Without knowing more about what the OP is trying to accomplish exactly I thought it better to just provide a simple solution that he can tweak to suit his needs.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do this

```
UPDATE table SET updated_time = NOW() WHERE id < x
```

Given id belongs to table

in case you want some random data from the past

```
UPDATE test2 SET update_time = NOW() - interval rand()*120 day - interval rand()*36000 second WHERE id < x
```

Tweak it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps are just the number of seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:01).  If you start with a base timestamp, you can just add a random number of seconds since that number and you have random  dates.